# How to avoid an onPause() with mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have this method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unsuscribeFromMessageDispatcher(RaffleListActivity.this);
    Intent service = new Intent(this, AsyncIntentService.class);
    service.putExtra("TASK", TASKID_GET_RAFFLE_LIST);
    stopService(service);
    super.onPause();
}
```

And when I make the test, if fails in the `super.onPause();` How can I avoid this line with mockito?

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the error? What is your test?

Comment: My test only verifies if unsuscribeFromMessageDispatcher was called and also if stopService was. But when I run the test, it indicates me that super.onPause() crashes

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot do this with Mockito. But you can with [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(YourTestClass.class)
public class YourTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MemberModifier.suppress(MemberMatcher.method(YourParentClass.class, "onPause"));
        YourTestClass c = new YourTestClass();
          //super.onPause() will not be called here
        c.onPause();
    }
```